Identify TV show from 80s. Australian World War 2
I remember watching a TV mini-series when I was about 10ish so somewhere between 1988-1994 to give me 2 years either side. I watched it in Britain, was probably shown on the BBC as i don't remember adverts on it. 
For the life of me I cannot find details about it. I am 99.9% certain its not the Sullivans as none of that sounds like the parts I remember.
It was (I believe) about an Australian family who may have lived on a small farm, and followed them through World War 1, where the dad fought and World War 2 where his sons fought, i think there were at least three sons. 
I think one of the son's joined up before the other and died. This then lead to the Dad being very hostile to the other 2 when they joined up, and he may have disowned them.
At least one of the sons was captured by the Japanese and interned in a POW camp. Eventually this son and a friend (or possibly the other brother) are forced to dig their own graves and are beheaded. 
At some point later we see the Dad finding out about this and his regrets at the harsh way they parted. One of the sons may then have returned only to find the dad seriously ill.

This sounds like miniseries The Dirtwater Dynasty with Hugo Weaving from 1988.

"Dirtwater Dynasty" is the story of embittered rivalry, triumph and despair. The life of Richard Eastwick is told in a story spanning three generations and eight decades. Born in the London slums in 1878, he comes to Australia at age 20, with nothing but a handful of courage and a dream. He acquires land, marries and raises a family, wins loyal friends and makes bitter enemies, and builds a land and cattle ranching empire. Both world wars and the economic depression take their toll on his family. But his dream to create a dynasty gives him a reason to continue.

Pretty sure one of his sons was traumatized after being a POW in a Japanese prison. Here's a clip:




This sounds very, very close to it, though the trailer isn't ringing bells the synopsis is. I'll try to find more clips and accept your answer if i'm convinced enough

Having found more clips I am convinced that this is the correct answer. Thank you it was driving me crazy

No problem. Sorry if it was too vague, it's an old one... Pretty sure he did have at least 3 sons and also that the first one died in WWI.

Yes first one did and another had PTSD from WW2. The answer was perfect, got me far closer than I ever did on all my searching. Now to get it on DVD.
